Irrationality measure, music and dissonance
I have been thinking about consonance in acoustics for a long time, specifically where two frequencies sound more consonant together if their ratio is a rational number with a small denominator (or is close to it). In music, 12 tone EDO is based on the fact that $2^{k/12}$ approximates $3/2$ for $k=7$ and $4/3$ for $k=5$ (and others) very well. On the other hand we have the tritone, which in Pythagorean tuning corresponds to a ratio of $729/512$ and in 12-EDO corresponds to $2^{6/12} = \sqrt2$, which are kinda close.
This makes me think, in some sense I can't put into math words, that $2^{7/12}$ is "closer" to the rationals than $\sqrt 2$ is, since the fifth interval is more consonant than the tritone. I've read a bit about irrationality measures and they seem to capture this concept: how closely an irrational number is approximated by the rationals. In the case of the Liouville–Roth irrationality measure, Wikipedia says that any irrational algebraic number has measure $2$, so it's not really useful for this case.
There's also Markov's constant, which seems the most promissing but I'm not sure. What are Markov's constants for $2^{k/12}$ with $k=1,\dots,11$? Do they match the consonance of the musical intervals they represent in the 12-EDO system? Does that make sense?
I'd also like to know your thoughts on the following, which might just be completely wrong: I tought about considering these "iterations" of Thomae's function given by
$$ d_n(x) = \min_{q \leq n, \; p \in \mathbb Z} \lvert q x - p \rvert $$
which vanish at the rationals with denominator less or equal to $n$. I thought that maybe, as $n \to \infty$, $n d_n$ converges to a function that is 0 at the rationals and lies in $(0,1)$ for irrational values of $x$. Then $x$ would be "closer" to the rationals as the smaller $n d_n(x)$ was. Maybe the function $\frac{1}{H_n} \sum_{k=1}^n d_k(x)$ with $H_n$ being the harmonic series also converges to something similar? Maybe these limits don't even exist.
Does this make any sense? I don't know. I would also appreciate any related opinions or info.
